# Adjustment for upper bound of VBA Loop

Tags: vba, loops

I'm trying to create a loop where the upper bound adjusts. However, when I run this loop, it exits when the p = 419 even though itotal_rows = 421. Why is this the case and how can I fix it.

```
    For p = 3 To itotal_rows
        If Not IsEmpty(wksSupervisor.Cells(p, 1)) Or p = wksSupervisor.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row Then
        
            'Insert row
            wksSupervisor.rows(p).Insert shift:=xlDown
            'Group Rows above next name
            wksSupervisor.rows(temp_row & ":" & p - 1).Group
            'start next grouping at next supervisor name
            temp_row = p + 1
            p = p + 1
            itotal_rows = wksSupervisor.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        End If
        'name position increased 1 row so we must also increment p again

        
    Next p
```

Comment: You could use a `while` loop instead.

Comment: Don't modify a collection you're iterating over. Or if you do, loop backwards.

Comment: The upper bound of the loop is determined when it first hits that line, it won't update it, there may be ways around that but I wouldn't recommend it, it obfuscates what the code is doing IMO.

Comment: The fact that the counter bounds of a For/Next loop do not change once the loop begins is an important characterstic of For/Next loops. This results in efficient loop execution, as comparisons against an terminating condition are not required on each loop cycle. Your scenario is not appropriate for the highly optimized For/Next loop. Use a loop that allows for dynamic terminating conditions,  such as While/Wend or Do/While.